# Automatically generating switch statements at compile time for sparse array indexing

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sparse-matrix, index-sequence

Is there a way to generate compile-time switch statements, for matching indices? For example if I have a sequence `1,5,8` and I want to match it to `0,1,2`, is there a way the compiler can generate a function at compile time, which when given 1,5,8 returns respectively 0,1,2. To better illustrate what I want, I have prepared this sparse array structure: https://godbolt.org/z/QpWVST

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <limits>

template<size_t depth, size_t Idx, size_t I, size_t...Is>
size_t get_idx()
{
    static_assert(Idx==I || sizeof...(Is)>0, "Index not found.");
    if constexpr(Idx==I) return depth;
    else return get_idx<depth+1, Idx,Is...>();
}

template<typename T, size_t... Is>
struct sparse_array
{
    constexpr static size_t N = sizeof...(Is);
    constexpr static size_t size() { return N; }

    T e[N];

    constexpr sparse_array() : e{} {}
    template<typename...type_pack>
    constexpr sparse_array(const type_pack&... pack) : e{ pack... }
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(type_pack) == size(), "Argument count must mach array size.");
    }

    template<size_t I>
    constexpr size_t idx()
    {
        return get_idx<0, I, Is...>();
    }

    size_t idx(const size_t i)
    {
        // how to achieve somethig like this?
        return idx<i>();
    }

    constexpr T& at(size_t idx)
    {
        return e[idx];
    }
};

template<typename T, size_t...Is>
auto make_dense_array(std::index_sequence<Is...>&& seq)
{
    return sparse_array<T, Is...>{};
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
using dense_array = decltype(make_dense_array<T>(std::declval<std::make_index_sequence<N>>()));

size_t test()
{
    dense_array<int, 3> a;
    sparse_array<int,1,5,8> b;
    return b.idx<8>();
}
```

I want to be able to also pass in runtime variables, which would go through a switch with the indices and return the appropriate corresponding index. The only idea I have for solving this, involves generating an array of the `Is...` sequence, and then having a for loop with if statements in order to return the correct index. The other option being, using a map (but this is also not compile-time). The `sparse_array` would in general be very small, and I would have liked to be able to do most things compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
static constexpr size_t idx(size_t i)
{
    size_t j = 0;
    if(!(... || (j++, i == Is))) {
        throw "Index out of range!";
    }
    return j-1;
}
```

It might be a bit tricky to read, but should do what you want, if I understood correctly. After instantiation this is basically equivalent to a series of `if else` going left-to-right through the indices in `Is`.

You can make it more readable by separating the body of the fold expression into a lambda. You should also replace the `throw` expression with whatever is sensible for you.

With the `constexpr` qualifier this can be reused for the template version as well:

```
template<size_t I, auto s = idx(I)>
static constexpr size_t idx() {
    return s;
}
```

(Putting the result in the template default argument guarantees compile time evaluation.)

This will not be the most well-performing code, sharing the same problems a manually written `switch` statement has. Depending on the predictability of the inputs, the many branches may be often mispredicted, in which case a (mostly) branchless version would be preferable. This can be achieved by modifying the fold expression appropriately.

If the number of indices is not small, a loop through a properly constructed static array would be preferable for instruction cache locality:

```
static constexpr size_t idx(size_t i)
{
    static constexpr std::array ind{Is...};
    size_t j = 0;
    for(; j < ind.size() && i != ind[j]; j++);
    if(j == ind.size())
        throw "Index out of range!";
    return j;
}
```

Again, it might be preferable to replace the early exit in the loop.

If the array is even larger, it might be useful to not only use a declared array with loop, but implement binary search on that array properly.

Standard algorithms like `std::any_of`, `std::find` and `std::binary_search` could be used instead of the manual search implementations. However these algorithms will be `constexpr` only in C++20 and so this would limit the use here.

Comment: Seems to be exactly what I wanted. I had a similar version, but couldn't make it work because of some of my functions requiring compile time expressions. This looks good though, not hard to read either (at least for me).

Comment: @lightxbulb I added some more information, since except for very small number of indices, you really should use a different approach.

Comment: I realize that for larger arrays one can use map and unordered_map, both of which are runtime, however. I assume that perfect hashing may also be achieved at compile time, but this is way beyond what I need and what I am going for. My arrays won't usually extend beyond 10 items, which is also the reason why I use static arrays for the data storage.